# Irfanview: How to stop gif images from overriding resize settings

Tags: png, gif

I have set my Irfan View to automatically Scall all Images to window size. This works great for normal images. However I have noticed that, instead of fitting gifs into the window the same way it does normal images, it always tries to give them full height. Therefore when a gif is wider than the window when resized to fit the height of the window, the window will be enlarged to fit the width.

This is very disturbing when browsing images, especially since I use them for reference -> I need the 2nd half of the screen for the program I am working in and if ifran view resizes, it covers up part of the other program. Manually resizing the window does then produce the desired effect, however this is just painful.

Is there any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try “View” → “Display options (window mode)” →
then “fit images to window width” / “height”.
12 options there:!/, yet I'm not sure if it
works on GIFs or just photographs.

Comment: Thats what I was using too for a while. Some gifs follow it some dont. idk what to do